# Using Azure AD Roles or Groups to restrict access to certain pages?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, authorization, azure-ad-b2c

I'm looking to create a user register web app using Azure B2C. Where a customer company would allow users to register a local account and fill in a profile (including uploading a picture to their profile. If anyone has any tips there please go ahead! But that's not the point of this question).

This profile is viewable by the user themselves and the administrator(s). Users should only be able to see and edit their own info. Admins should be able to access both the page for their personal profile and a table of every user's details (with the ability to edit).

I want this to be done through Azure status. So if my user is a global admin in azure ad then they should be an admin user in my application. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I afraid there is no inheritance relationship between global admin and application admin role in your application.

In your scenario, you'll create an application with `User.ReadWrite.All` permission and [define a admin role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps) for it. As the global admin won't have too much, you can grant the global admin admin role manually, then the admin will be able to access every user's details. Others will only be able to see and edit their own info.

[Here](https://joonasw.net/view/using-groups-vs-using-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps) is the difference between using groups and using application riles for authorization.